# Foreign key field null in @OneToOne mapping with Hibernate/JPA

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

I have two entities, `Document` and `BodyElement`, and trying to persist them with Hibernate 4.2. `mtdt_t` populates correctly, but the foreign key `docid` in the `mtdt_body_t` table is `NULL`.

I see hibernate trying to insert without the `docid` value. `insert into mtdt_body_t values ( )`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mtdt_t")
public class Document implements Serializable {

    @Id  
    @Column(name = "docid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String docid;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn
    @JoinColumn(name = "docid", nullable = false)
    private BodyElement bodyElement;

    public String getDocid() {
        return docid;
    }

    public void setDocid(String docid) {
        this.docid = docid;
    }

    public BodyElement getBodyElement() {
        return bodyElement;
    }

    public void setBodyElement(BodyElement bodyElement) {
        this.bodyElement = bodyElement;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "mtdt_body_t")
public class BodyElement implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "docid", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Document document;

    public BodyElement() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Document getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

}
```

I left off another field. In `Document` I have,

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderColumn
@JoinColumn(name = "docid", nullable = false)
@XmlPath("head/meta/kb:keywords/kb:keyword")
private Set<Keyword> keywords;
```

In the `Keyword` class I have the foreign key mapped as,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "docid", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
@XmlTransient
private Document document;
```

and that `docid` field is never `NULL`.

Is there anything special about the `@OneToOne` Mapping compared to `@OneToMany`? I just mimicked what I had done for `@OneToMany` on the `@OneToOne` field.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. The OrderColumn annotation is specified on a OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship or on an element collection. The OrderColumn annotation is specified on the side of the relationship that references the collection that is to be ordered. The order column is not visible as part of the state of the entity or embeddable class.
   [link to documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html)
2. You have mistake in mapping. You forgot about mappedBy attribute. It means that that relation between entites has already been mapped, so you don't do that twice. You just say "Hey it's done over there" by using mappedBy attribute ([following by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962946/1085100)). And here is useful example: [Hibernate – One-To-One Example (Annotation)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: I followed mkyong's example using `mappedBy` but it still left off the `docid` field. This time the `docid` column wasn't even present.